# Page over http gets cached while over https it doesn't

Tags: http, http-caching

I have a webapplication. The bootstrap page shouldn't be cached but chrome always gets the page from cache, while it doesn't show that behaviour over https, where it works correctly.

My headers are as follows:

```
Request URL:https://localhost:7002/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,de-CH;q=0.6,de;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:7002
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.56 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:2215
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 23 Apr 2013 10:19:03 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=WrSkR2gXB3Jkycwhtzmhwgkpzv4Nn1V6nshsMWZyHl924cNp6Y6L!-1407827785; path=/; HttpOnly
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
```

The headers over http are exactly the same.

I tried already max-age, no-store, must-revalidate, ETag, Last-Modified, Pragma in the HTTP Header and in the meta http-equiv, but nothing seems chrome to prevent caching.

Any ideas how to prevent chrome from caching?

PS: Safari on iOS shows the same behaviour.